# Two Rows with Circles in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

how can I draw five rows of circles in D3?

° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° °

° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° °

° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° °

° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° °

° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° °

**My HTML**

```
<body>
     <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="355px" height="355px" viewBox="0 0 351 351" enable-background="new 0 0 351 351" xml:space="preserve">

        <g id="graph">  
        </g>

     </svg>
```

I started like this:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var g = svg.select("#graph");
var rectValues = [0, 17, 34, 51, 68, 85, 102, 119, 136, 153, 170, 187, 204, 221, 238, 255, 272, 289, 306, 323];

var rect = d3.select("body").select("svg").select("#graph").selectAll("rect")
    .data(rectValues);

     rect.enter().append("rect")
       .attr("rx",100)
       .attr("ry",100)
       .attr("x", function(d) { return d })
       .attr("y", ???)
       .attr("width",15)
       .attr("height",15);
```

But I do not know if I have to include more than one array(data) "even if x and y are the same values"?

Thats my fist version. It works(!) but it is not really a efficient version for the further purpose.

```
var rectX;
var rectY = 5;
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var g = svg.select("#graph");

for (var index1 = 0; index1<20; ++index1){
    rectX = 5;

    for (var index2 = 0; index2<20; ++index2) {

    d3.select("body").select("svg").select("#graph").append("rect")
                .attr("rx",100)
                .attr("ry",100)
                .attr("x", rectX)
                .attr("y", rectY)
                .attr("width",15)
                .attr("height",15)
                rectX=rectX+17;
            }
            rectY=rectY+17;
      }
```

Comment: This seems like a simple enough task where you could just do this naively, anyways could we see your `<svg>`?

Comment: Maybe it is. I have just started programming.  Yes, I have a first version (above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the circles have to come one below the other the x should not be:

```
var rectValues = [0, 17, 34, 51, 68, 85, 102, 119, 136, 153, 170, 187, 204, 221, 238, 255, 272, 289, 306, 323];
```

It should be

```
var rectValues = [0, 17, 34, 51, 68, 0, 17, 34, 51, 68,0, 17, 34, 51, 68,0, 17, 34, 51, 68,0, 17, 34, 51, 68,];
```

Here i am repeating the x values after 5 points, the reason is 6th circle should come below the 1st circle and 12th circle should come below 6th circle.
So the 1st circle, 6th circle 12th circle. 18th circle ... all have same x value.

**Note**: In D3 the data drives the Document(DOM) so the name **D**ata **D**riven **D**ocument (D3).

Make a variable yPos

```
var yPos = 20;
```

Make circles like this:

```
d3.select("body").select("svg").select("#graph").selectAll("rect")
    .data(rectValues);

     rect.enter().append("rect")
       .attr("rx",100)
       .attr("ry",100)
       .attr("x", function(d) { return d })
       .attr("y", function(d, i) { return (yPos * parseInt(i/5)) })
       .attr("width",15)
       .attr("height",15);
```

See this line

```
.attr("y", function(d, i) { return (yPos * parseInt(i/5)) })
```

Here `i` is the index of the array element under process. So this `parseInt(i/5)` is going to give me the column index (Thus you don't need a loop like you have mentioned in the ticket).

Full working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/f30mb5h8/)

Hope this helps!